# Commerce free shipping for orders over €500

Tags: commerce

I am carrying on with this project where we are supposed to ship for free for orders over €500. I have two rules; `Free shipping` and `NL/BE`. I make an address based comparison and role based comparison for NL/BE and amount based in Free shipping. Now, the problem is, when I test if the customer places an order for over €500 and the shipping address is in Belgium, I am still asked whether I want a free shipping or a NL/BE shipping. Obviously this shouldn't happen. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

These are my rules:

```
{ "commerce_shipping_service_nl_be" : {
    "LABEL" : "Rate NL\/BE",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_order", "rules", "commerce_shipping" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "commerce_order" : { "label" : "Order", "type" : "commerce_order" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "commerce_order_compare_address" : {
          "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ],
          "address_field" : "commerce_customer_shipping|commerce_customer_address",
          "address_component" : "country",
          "value" : "BE"
        }
      },
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "6" : "6" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_shipping_service_rate_order" : {
          "shipping_service_name" : "nl_be",
          "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-order" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
}
```

and

```
{ "commerce_shipping_service_free_shipping" : {
    "LABEL" : "Rate Free shipping",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_shipping" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "commerce_order" : { "type" : "commerce_order", "label" : "Order" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "4" : "4", "6" : "6" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_shipping_service_rate_order" : {
          "shipping_service_name" : "free_shipping",
          "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-order" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I at last managed to find out. I should have paid more attention to the video I've watched. What I needed to do was add the exact opposite condition to `NL/BE` rule, that is `if the order's total amount is lower than €500`.